# onBeforeNavigate returns tabId which doesn't exist

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make theses line work:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(function(details) {
chrome.tabs.update(details.tabId, {url: "http://www.google.com"}, function() {});
}, {url: [{hostEquals: 'yahoo.com'}]});
```

Sometimes, we get the error:
Error during tabs.update: No tab with id: 294.

Strange, do you have a reason for that?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score -1):

It seems that onBeforeNavigate works also for autocomplete url with prefetch maybe ...

Using onBeforeNavigate instead of onBeforeNavigate removes the bug!